# Detecting color and 'coordinates' of a cell in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to detect if the cell is black or white or not changed at a specific 'coordinate'. To put it in code, it should work like, if cell is white, then return cell[row][col]=1 and if the cell is black then cell[row][col]=0. Every cell should start out as cell[row][col]=2 since it is neither black or white. Everytime it is clicked, it changes to either 1 or 0.

My code so far:

JS & jQuery:

```
var white=true;
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 5, 5) );

$( "td" ).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('played')) {
      return;
    }
    $(this).addClass('played');

    var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
    var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 5) + 1;
    var col = ( index % 5 ) + 1;
    if (white==true){
       $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'white' );
       white=false
    }
    else if (white==false){
       $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'black' );
       white=true;
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
html{
    background-color:#E2F8FA;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

HTML:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: where is `grid += "</table>"` ?

Comment: @Banzay wat lol